# 2010 Jetta Stuck in park

Tags: transmission

Shifter won't move. I checked all the fuses. Brake lights work. No foot on brake indicator on dash. I don't know what it is. Have no problem pushing the manual release under the shifter. Check engine light is on. What could be the issue?

Comment: Pull the codes from the OBD2 connector and post them.

Comment: U0101
49409
532
1315

Comment: You will need to take it to a qualified shop for a diagnosis.

Comment: Will the shop be able to hook up directly to the tcm to check that it's working or not? I'm really hoping something just came loose.